# Nested Layouts (GridBagLayout inside a FlowLayout)

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout, flowlayout

How can I position my labels with this code?  It seems that gridbaglayout is not working here, especially the gridbagconstraints.  Even if I change the gridx and gridy values, the labels are not moving.

I need to make it in like 3 even columns, 1 column = 1 panel

```
package nest;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class nested extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        JFrame f=new JFrame("Bio Data");
        JPanel p1=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel p2=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        //JPanel p3=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());            
        GridBagConstraints c1=new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints c2=new GridBagConstraints();            
        JLabel l1=new JLabel("aa");
        JLabel l2=new JLabel("bb");            
        c1.gridx=1;
        c1.gridy=1;
        p1.add(l1, c1);            
        c2.gridx=4;
        c2.gridy=4;
        p2.add(l2, c2);
        f.add(p1);
        f.add(p2);            
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(800,500);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing gridx and gridy does not change the actual position of the labels, but rather the order/format that the labels will be displayed in. If you have something in gridx 4 but nothing in gridx 1,2 or 3 then that object will be the first column.
Also, it woulld be very odd to put a new panel in each column since you can put things in different rows of the gridBagLayout. Here is a short example of a gridBagLayout inside a flowLayout with three different columns of labels:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Insets;


public class nest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    nest frame = new nest();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public nest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel.add(panel_1);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel_1 = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel_1.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 27, 0};
        gbl_panel_1.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 16, 0};
        gbl_panel_1.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panel_1.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel_1.setLayout(gbl_panel_1);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("New label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridy = 0;
        panel_1.add(lblNewLabel_1, gbc_lblNewLabel_1);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = 0;
        panel_1.add(lblNewLabel, gbc_lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("New label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel_2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel_2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblNewLabel_2.gridx = 2;
        gbc_lblNewLabel_2.gridy = 0;
        panel_1.add(lblNewLabel_2, gbc_lblNewLabel_2);

        JLabel lblLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblLabel.gridx = 2;
        gbc_lblLabel.gridy = 1;
        panel_1.add(lblLabel, gbc_lblLabel);
    }

}
```

I created this with the Google WindowBuilder. Note that you don't necessarily need to set the columnWidths, rowHeights, columnWeights, or rowWeights (and it is better not to sometimes when you have dynamic content). Hopefully this helps.